# Dropdown `value` must be an array when `multiple` is set. Received type: `[object String]`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form

I am getting this error

**Dropdown `value` must be an array when `multiple` is set. Received type: `[object String]`.**

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-torvalds-lhe9d

I already provide a default **value blank array**.

```
<Dropdown
        {...restProps}
        value={value || []}
        {...props.input}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the error because of `{...props.input}` which has a property `value`

```
name: "zones"
value: "" // <--- this is [object String]
type: undefined
onBlur: function () {}
onChange: function () {}
onFocus: function () {}
```

Which is overwriting the `value` attribute you set right before it

```
 <Dropdown
      {...restProps}
      value={value || []}
      {...props.input} // <--- the value here is overwriting the value attribute before it.
      clearable
      fluid
      multiple
```

So, to fix this, just move the `value` attribute one step down :

```
<Dropdown
      {...restProps}
      {...props.input}
      value={value || []}
      clearable
      fluid
      multiple
```

Answer (score 0):

The spread from input means that the value from the root component (a "" in this case) was being passed into the Dropdown component.

I've forked and fixed.

https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-wildflower-e9t3n

Basically replacing the following

```
let { value = [], ...restProps } = props.input;
```

The spread is handy but sometimes it can confuse the mater. For Components with only a few props, I recommend passing them in explicitly.